# How to position ::before and ::after above parent and next to each other

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

How to position two pseudoelements `::before` & `::after` above the parent  and next to each other? Both before and after are text values. They differ in color and content.

A perfect solution would be to make a `::before` element, give it `display:block` so that it does appear above the parent and then give itself an `::after` but it's not possible to define a pseudoelement on another pseudoelement.

```
<h1>
    <svg></svg>
    <span> 
      Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying 
    </span>
</h1>
span::before{
  content:'Lorem ipsum, or lipsum';
}

span::after{
  content:'.';
  color: red;
}
```

**The expected result is:**

```
Lorem ipsum, or lipsum.

Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying
```

The content of before is usually shorter than the content of  but not always.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Sounds a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The possible solutions very much could depend on actual string lengths and context. So you should edit your OP and add in real world examples.

Comment: James Coyle: maybe you're right. I tried to specify the OP providing code and the expected output.

Comment: @user2923339 You are using a `<span>` element. Does that mean that the span should be an inline element and remain an inline element, even with the added `::before` and `::after` content?

Comment: @yunzen there is no need for my element to be an inline element. The whole part is contained within <h1> tag.

Comment: @user2923339 That would be important information than should go into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It occurred impossible to style ::before and ::after to stick next to each other and above their parent independently of the size of the 3 elements.
I introduced a new element in the DOM structure:

```
        <h1 class="title">
            <span class="title__main" :data-before="mainTitle" :data-after="."></span>
            <span class="title__sub">{{subTitle}}</span>
        </h1>
```

and now it's a lot easier to position everything.

Answer (score -1):

```css
h1.extra span {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: gold;
}

h1.extra span::before {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: attr(data-before);
  order: -1;
}

h1.extra span::after {
  font-size: 1rem;
  content: attr(data-after);
  order: -1;
  color: red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="extra">
  <svg></svg>
  <span data-before="Lorem ipsum, or lipsum" data-after="..."> 
  Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying 
</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Yunzen thanks for your solutions. However, LGSon is right. The solution breaks if we amend the string sizes. The OP was edited - I added an information about exemplary text values. Text2 is a dot text1 is usually short and text inside <span> is long.

Comment: Thanks for the next solution. This one breaks if <span>'s text is shorter than the text in ::before

Comment: @user2923339 add `flex-grow:1` to after element and consider `flex` istead of `inline-flex`

Comment: @user2923339 I did some changes. Maybe it suits your needs now?